# Is sending mouse and keyboard events the only way to manipulate a windows gui application without decompiling it?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, message

I have a .exe file ,which is a music player with gui .

I can post mouse click messages to the player window to play .mp3 files ,or to pause or stop music playing.

But can I reach the mechanism behind the message loops ?

Like using command lines to directly perform opening .mp3 file actions .(it surely doesn't provide command line functions though)

Comment: Have you tried looking at the exe/any dlls packaged with it in Resource Viewer? Depending on how it is designed, it might have a public function that does the main work of loading and playing the mp3. However, getting it working may or may not be an easy task. It would probably be easier to look a the open source options and write your own simple player.

Comment: This question's a bit impossible to answer without knowing the full details of the application, its libraries, etc., as Dominic pointed out. Also trying to do this for an opaque kind of application that isn't designed to be used a library will very likely entail more work than just designing your own MP3 player or finding an open source library or project you can work with -- actually pretty much exactly what Dominic said. :-D

Comment: If the application allows you to launch it by double-clicking the .mp3 file, you can do that in software.  See the ShellExecute and ShellExecuteEx functions.

Comment: @Dominic McDonnell So ,it's acceptable to just post keyboard and mouse events to a gui application rather than trying to figure out what's behind this mechanism , am I right ? I just want to know the "standard" way to manipulate another gui application using my own program .

Comment: There is no "standard" way to manipulate a closed-source application with no public API.

Comment: @iouvxz, the standard way is either through the command line or if the application is designed to, through a direct api which can vary a lot. If you don't have a direct api documented it's probably not designed to do that. There are a lot of times in the past that Microsoft has provided direct APIs for things and not released them to the public and people have ratted them out and started using them through things like Resource Viewer. As HarryJohnston said look at the ShellExecute functions. That is the standard way

Comment: You may be able to use UI Automation to control the application. That's how assistive technologies do it.